# google maps mapping the coordinates with textboxes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The below code is working fine if i give the coordinates in the text boxes named start and end for the lat long values for directions and click on submit button.

```
<script>
function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 7,
        center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });
}
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
        destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    },
    function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I want to get the coordinates in the text boxes when i click on the place in map. I have the code for getting the coodrinates by clicking on the map.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('latitude').value = e.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('longitude').value = e.latLng.lng();
});
```

But i am finding it difficult to map the click for start and end receptively.
When the user first time click on map a textbox for start has to get populated. When he clicks again textbox for end has to get populated. Later if he wants to change only end point how will i map his click to textbox corresponding to end??  Please help

Comment: You should fix the title of this post. The current one tells nothing about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I have assumed correct, you want to the lat long when you click on map,

Try Below

```js
var map;
var geocoder;
var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };



function initMap() {
  var myOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.85, -85.61),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    getLocation(event.latLng);
  });

  var marker;
  function getLocation(location) {
    
    document.getElementById('lat').value=location.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value=location.lng();
    getAddress(location);
  }

  function getAddress(latLng) {
    geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
                     function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if(results[0]) {
          document.getElementById("address").value = results[0].formatted_address;
        }
        else {
          document.getElementById("address").value = "No results";
        }
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("address").value = status;
      }
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script><input type="text" id="address" size="30"><br><input type="text" id="lat" size="10"><input type="text" id="lng" size="10">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

I have added extra function which will tell you address as well. Hope this helps to you!

Comment: No i need 2 lat long. one for start address and other for end address. First click will give Start value and second click will give Destination/End value for direction

Comment: Similar way you can achieve this. Store the value in array for start and end when user click. As u said "But i am finding it difficult to map the click for start and end receptively. Please help" has got resolved by above.

Comment: I have tried it and not able to achieve that. When the user first time click on map a textbox for start has to get populated. When he clicks again textbox for end has to get populated. Later if he wants to change only end point how will i map his click to textbox corresponding to end?? Please understand my question and give me some suggestion.